# I accidentally refactored a QT class

Tags: qt

I accidentally refactored a QT class (QJsonValue) and now nothing is working. I am using the QT creator IDE. Is there a way to undo the refactor? I refactored from [QJsonValue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) into [QJsonObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) so refactoring QJsonObejct into QJsonValue won't solve much.[image: List of errors]

Is there way an easy way to undo it?

Comment: Get the original headers from the repository or reinstall Qt.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no," you can't undo a Qt refactor. Use the maintenance tool to delete and reinstall the component with that class.